Front porch ceiling and swing framing questions
I am currently in the process of remodeling our front porch after finding some water and insect damage. My wife and I want to make two improvements to the space that I have some questions about.
The first is adding a wood ceiling as opposed to the aluminum soffit that was previously installed. I am concerned that the 24" OC 2x6 trusses will not be able to support the weight of a wood ceiling.
Attached are two pictures that should give you an idea of what I am working with. My guess is the trusses used for this first story porch roof were repurposed to match the pitch of the full roof above our garage and the second story roof. They are only toe nailed in to a 2x6 ledger board.
Assuming I cant use the trusses what would be the easiest way to support the wood ceiling we want? I would prefer for the ceiling boards to run parallel, length wise, with the brick wall.
Second we want to add a single person porch swing in the corner of the porch captured in one of the attached photos. I already plan to frame this separately but I dont know what type of support I need to add.
The span between the beam and my house is roughly 7.5'. Would two sistered 2x6 pieces of lumber suffice?



A 3/4" tongue and groove wood ceiling is really not that heavy.
Add galvanized angle braces to the top truss chord to tie the to the 2x6.
Sister 2x4s to the bottom chords and tie them to the 2x6 above the brick wall with hurricane ties.
That will hold a wood ceiling with no problem. Remember to plan for any electric for lighting or outlets before closing things up.
Sistered 2x6 will be plenty strong for your swing.

I did consider reinforcing the connection to the ledger but had concerns it may weaken the ledger adding additional screws / risking splitting. Or are my concerns misplaced?

Yes, the brackets and proper nails are made for such purposes. Just know a nail in every hole is not required.  Simpson N-10 nails or connector screws would be good 1 1/2"long.

Sorry last question. Can a 3/4” board span 24” OC without sagging?

Yes if it is solid wood and not OSB or particle board. I have a stained wood ceiling on my balcony. 3/4" x 6" tongue and groove pine. nailed to the bottom chords of trusses that are 24" on center
